# While Running Flutter app it is showing swift compiler error and below errors

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported

Uncategorized (Xcode): Command SwiftDriver emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

Error (Xcode): no such module '__ObjC'
/Users/sahil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dionrxuxxrlnqqfrbtwgtgxpiqae/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.private.swiftinterface:9:18

Error (Xcode): failed to verify module interface of 'Runner' due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug
/Users/sahil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dionrxuxxrlnqqfrbtwgtgxpiqae/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.private.swiftinterface:0:0

Error (Xcode): no such module '__ObjC'
/Users/sahil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dionrxuxxrlnqqfrbtwgtgxpiqae/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.swiftinterface:9:18

Error (Xcode): failed to verify module interface of 'Runner' due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug
/Users/sahil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dionrxuxxrlnqqfrbtwgtgxpiqae/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.swiftinterface:0:0

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max

Comment: Can you add more information such as your `flutter doctor` report, Xcode version and packages you are using?

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-arm64, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!

Xcode version
          Xcode: 14.3 (21812)

Comment: @Advait I have added the info

Comment: I don't think I am able to debug the issue, I asked you to add the info so that it's clear there's no problem with the installation.